# Special Datetime format as string which looks like double

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I have to create a xml file for a external app I have no description for the file structure, so I have to it by reverse engineering. The original required file has the attribute

```
LastChange = "43061.2997590394"
```

I think this is a result af a special DateTime format.

`DateTime.Parse("43061.2997590394")` throws an exception.

Have anyone an idea what format this is ?

Comment: I guess that is a `TimeSpan`'s some `.Total*` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
double oaValue = double.Parse("43061.2997590394", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate( oaValue );  // Result: 11/22/2017 07:11:39
```

Remarks from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx):

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose
>   integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30
>   December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on
>   that day divided by 24. For example, midnight, 31 December 1899 is
>   represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25;
>   midnight, 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29
>   December 1899 is represented by -1.25.
>
> The base OLE Automation Date is midnight, 30 December 1899. The
>   minimum OLE Automation date is midnight, 1 January 0100. The maximum
>   OLE Automation Date is the same as DateTime.MaxValue, the last moment
>   of 31 December 9999.